# Spring boot consuming high memory

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring boot service deployed to Linux server, and the service is consuming like 684 Mb when is checked this in spring boot admin and drops to 38 Mb for sometime, but this service is just a simple controller and which sends a modal html to the front end. Is there a way we can reduce the memory consumption to this service. Roughly for every 30 secs we get a call for this service. Please let me know any memory optimization techniques that I can use. Appreciate your help. It does have spring boot actuator (FYI)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gradle you can see the full dependency list via command gradle --scan, and then you can exclude some of the repeated or unused dependencies.

Comment: am using maven, can you please share same for MVN, and one more thing this is RAM(heap) memory consumption. FYI